# How does the compiler deduce which version of std::vector::begin() to call when passing it to std::vector::insert?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, stdvector

I am trying to make my own mini-vector class and I am attempting to replicate some of the functions, but I can not get them to behave the same way when passing calls such as `begin()` and `end()` as parameters - the compiler doesn't deduce the right version. Here is an example:

```
template<typename T>
class Iterator
{
public:
Iterator() {}
};

template<typename T>
class ConstIterator
{
public:
ConstIterator() {}
};

template <typename T>
class MyList {
   public:
    MyList() {}

    Iterator<T> Begin()
    {
        return Iterator<T>();
    }

    ConstIterator<T> Begin() const
    {
        return Iterator<T>();
    }

    void Insert(ConstIterator<T> it) 
    {

    }
};


int main() {
    MyList<int> myList;

    myList.Insert(myList.Begin());
}
```

At `myList.Insert(myList.Begin());` it does not try to use the correct version of `Begin()`, the const one.

From what I can tell in the std::vector implementation, there are two versions of begin() - one returns an `iterator` and one returns a `const_iterator`. The only other difference between them is that one is a const method (the one returning a const_iterator).

```
_NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 iterator begin() noexcept {
    auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
    return iterator(_My_data._Myfirst, _STD addressof(_My_data));
}

_NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
    auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
    return const_iterator(_My_data._Myfirst, _STD addressof(_My_data));
}
```

Many methods, like std::vector::insert take a const_iterator parameter:

```
_CONSTEXPR20 iterator insert(const_iterator _Where, const _Ty& _Val) { // insert _Val at _Where
    return emplace(_Where, _Val);
}

_CONSTEXPR20 iterator insert(const_iterator _Where, _Ty&& _Val) { // insert by moving _Val at _Where
    return emplace(_Where, _STD move(_Val));
}
```

However, there is nothing in the insert method that would make the compiler use the const version of begin().
Which means it has to deduce by the return type alone, but as far as I know that's not possible?
How is it achieving it then?

Comment: `std::vector` simply has a separate overload for each iterator https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: @AlanBirtles "(until C++11)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no deduction. If `myList` is not `const`-qualified, then the non-`const` version of `Begin()` is called for `myList.Begin()`. Otherwise the `const` version is called. How you use the result of `myList.Begin()` is not relevant.

The standard library avoids your issue by providing a conversion from the non-const iterator to the const iterator. For example you could give `ConstIterator` a constructor which accepts a `Iterator`, which you must have anyway to make the `return Iterator<T>();` statement in your `const` version of `Begin()` work (assuming that is not a typo).

Comment: You are right, it needs a conversion, however an explicit conversion constructor cause ambiguities in many places as now it can be both a const iterator and a regular one everywhere it's passed, so some template methods that take multiple parameters of type T which are supposed to be iterators, can't deduce what type of iterator it should be.
I'm looking around the stl implementation to see how exactly they do the conversion.
It seems their iterator inherits const_iterator, but I don't see a conversion constructor or operator yet.

Comment: @ulakblade You may be using wrong terminology, but the constructor must not be `explicit`. If it is `explicit` then it cannot be used for implicit conversions as expected here. There is no ambiguity issue between the iterators. Firstly you don't need to overload functions on both iterators, choose only a const iterator if the function doesn't modify the referenced values and a non-const iterator otherwise. But even if you have both, the overload that doesn't require a conversion will be preferred.

Comment: For templated functions it doesn't matter because they are supposed to take the iterator type directly as a template parameter, so that it will always match the type of iterator given in the argument exactly. Implicit conversions on deduced types are not possible anyway.

Comment: @ulakblade Which standard library implementation are you looking at?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant implicit.
What I meant for the ambiguity is this - https://godbolt.org/z/6G19asYsb
The Distance function - the arguments passed to it are ambiguous even tho it can convert from one iterator type to the other

Comment: @ulakblade That deduction failure is expected and you would have the same failure with `std::vector` and `std::distance`. The user of `std::distance` is expected to make sure that they are passing exactly equal iterator types as arguments (or alternatively that they make one of the two arguments a non-deduced context by using a braced-init-list instead of an expression). Standard library containers have a `cbegin` member function to allow a user to assure that they get a const iterator, which the user should be using instead of `begin` in your example.

Comment: Ah I see, so this is entirely proper behavior then. So I guess there are no more issues on the matter, thank you very much for the help.